# Behavior of float that is used as an integer

Tags: c, floating-point

Suppose we have to use a float variable as a counter - for example

```
float i = 1;
float previ = 0;
do 
{
   previ = i;
}
while (i++);
```

At what value of i will (i-previ) differ from 1? Will that difference still be an integer, or will it become a rational non-integer?

Comment: Why not put it in a loop and see what you get?

Comment: @perfanoff wont the difference be zero always in your example? since your assigning i to previ?

Comment: Sorry, I have fixed the code.

Comment: I'm asking at which point using a float and an int as counters stop producing equivalent results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the most common implementation of floating point, IEEE 754, the first integer that is not representable with 32-bit binary floating point is 2<sup>24</sup>+1 (16,777,217). At this point, 2<sup>24</sup> (16,777,216) and 2<sup>24</sup>+2 (16,777,218) are representable.

When you add 1 to 16,777,216, the exact mathematical result is 16,777,217. Since this is not representable, it is rounded to a representable value. The most common default rounding mode is round-to-nearest. However, both 16,777,216 and 16,777,218 are equally distant from 16,777,217. In case of ties, the value with the even low bit (in the floating-point significand) is chosen. So 16,777,216 is returned.

Thus, when one is repeatedly added to a floating-point value, starting with zero, counting continues until 16,777,216 is reached, and then 16,777,216 is produced continuously.

The reason that 16,777,217 is the first unrepresentable integer is that the IEEE 754 32-bit binary format uses 24 bits for the significand (fraction portion). (23 bits are explicitly stored. The high bit is implicitly one for normal values.) Thus, all integers that can be represented in 24 bits are representable. 2<sup>24</sup> nominally requires 25 integer bits (from 2<sup>24</sup> down to 2<sup>0</sup>). However, using only the 24 high bits does not introduce any error (it is represented as 1•2<sup>24</sup>), since the missing low bit would be zero. Conversely, 16,777,217 cannot be represented since it would need the missing bit to be one.

Comment: Just tested adding float++, and was wondering why it stops at 16777216.